# TP-Linc AC600 wireless USB dongle was found by installation once, but never again. Ideas?

Tags: wireless, system-installation

I did an install of latest LTS on one small vivobook by plugging the AC600 wireless dongle in before the start and then going through the install.  I was prompted for wireless password early in the process and everything worked.  Wireless worked on the installed system, and dmesg shows rtw_8821ce "enabling device" line.

I then tried on a different vivobook, but was never prompted for the wireless password and the wireless device doesn't show up either from live image or after install.

I went back and tried the live image again on the first vivobook, but the dongle didn't work there either and starting the installation process didn't prompt for wireless passwords.

So between these two systems it worked exactly once for reasons I can't guess.  The drivers are clearly in the LTS somewhere, but the installer mostly just never loads them.  What I wonder is if the USB dongle usually isn't even powered up when the probes are run, but I don't know how to check for sure if that's what's going on.

I also tried the newer version (non-LTS 23.10).

On the live image for 23.10, the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; uname -r` is:

```
0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5520]
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port [8086:a74d]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 3277:0036 ShineTech USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0c90 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:011e TP-Link AC600 wireless Realtek RTL8811AU [Archer T2U Nano]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0751 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. Mouose
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
6.5.0-9-generic
```

This makes it look like the USB dongle is at least powered on?

Note that the MEDIATEK device is the internal wireless card that I've read doesn't work on linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb; uname -r`

Comment: It may help if you're specific as to what exact system you're install; you mention *latest LTS* but this means what exactly?  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I assume, which has had three kernel stacks provided on its ISO's (5.15 or the GA, 5.19 & 6.2 being HWE kernels) but you didn't provide provide more than *latest LTS*. Further, hardware varies on machines, even when the same make/model (*particularly for popular models that are manufactured more than 3 months as newer/cheaper chips replace older chips*) so its possible your machines have different chips in them.

Answer (score 1):

8821ce is most likely an internal Wi-Fi module of your second laptop. It worked once and then failed to initialize for some reason. For your AC600 dongle you need to install an additional driver. Check this page out for more links:

https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-011e

Comment: By golly you're right, I was led astray because last time I tried with that laptop the wireless didn't function at all land the internet seemed to be saying MEDIATEK just don't work.  It works every time from the installed OS, I wonder what's changed that the installer doesn't seem to bring it up successfully now